# "bsoncxx::document is ambiguous." error while using C++ Mongodb driver 3.7.1

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am developing software based on C++ Mongodb driver 3.7.1 version.

I'm confronting a compiler error:

> bsoncxx::document is ambiguous

in `hint.hpp`, `client_session.hpp`,'change_stream.hpp' and `key_context.hpp` etc.
additional info:
when I use "bsoncxx::v_noabi::document", the compiler error disappears.
But I know I should not change the package code in C++ MongoDB Driver.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

[image]

Here are the project references:

[image]

Comment: That looks more like an Intellisense error than a compiler error. Can you quote the error number (it will be either of the form be Cnnnn or Ennnn).

Comment: Please show a [mre] and the full error message as text, not images

Comment: Does this produce an actual compiler error? Remember that Intellisense is a separate fast compiler that's job is to produce an answer as fast as possible. It will have false positives from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

OK the `Ennnn` format for the error codes mean these are Intellisense errors. Intellisense is a fast scanner meant to provide feedback on simple errors, as well auto complete features while you are typing. However it's not perfect and sometimes produces false positives. An Intellisense error will not prevent the real compiler from compiling your code.

You have a few options. You could turn off Intellisense (this is my choice, I find it is more trouble than it is worth). You could ignore it. You could rebuild the 'Intellisense database'. Sometimes Intellisense gets itself confused and if you nuke it, it sorts itself out. Find the `.vs` folder in your solution folder and delete it.